# не работает конструктор - окружность

Tags: c++

класс окружность Параметры: координаты центра, радиус. Методы: процедура инициализации полей, процедура вывода на экран значения полей объекта и функция, определяющая, находится ли некоторая точка с координатами x,y внутри окружности. Создал как смог, при компиляции выдаёт error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Circle
{
private:
   double x;
   double y;
   double r;
public:
Circle();
   Circle(double x=2, double y=2, double r=5);
   
};

 int Main(){
  if (x*x+y*y<=r*r)
{
  cout << "Точка принадлежит окружности." << endl;
} 
else 
{
  cout << "Точка не принадлежит окружности." << endl;
}
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас функция `int Main()` не является методом класса (находится снаружи) и следовательно не знает ничего о переменных `x, y, r`, однако вы их используете в данной функции

```
class Circle
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double r;
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(const double x0=2, const double y0=2, const double r0=5);

    int Main();   
};

int Circle::Main(){
    if (x*x+y*y<=r*r)
    {
        cout << "Точка принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << "Точка не принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

правда подозреваю что это `Main()`, которая `main()` обычно :)

P.S.

```
class Circle
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double r;
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(const double x0=2, const double y0=2, const double r0=5);

    void show();   
};

Circle::Circle()
    : x(0), y(0), r(0)
{}

Circle::Circle(const double x0, const double y0, const double r0)
    : x(x0), y(y0), r(r0)
{}

int Circle::show(){
    if (x*x+y*y<=r*r)
    {
        cout << "Точка принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << "Точка не принадлежит окружности." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

и использование в основном коде, например так:

```
Circle obj(10, 20, 5);
obj.show();
```

Comment: теперь ошибка сменилась на "undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: потому что как я написал выше похоже `main` - это все таки основная функция. т.е. замените Main на какой-то метод класса, например `IsInCircle`, затем раскройте свои конструкторы (а то они у вас без содержимого) и затем уже используйте класс - в настоящий момент у вас просто половина класса реализована

Comment: Прошу прощения за навязчивость, хотел уточнить про какой Main идёт речь, тот что вышел, или ниже?

Comment: у вас в программе обязательно есть главная функция - `int main()`, так ведь? теперь вам надо добавить код своего класса

Comment: Честно, самому неловко, но я вообще не понимаю о чём идёт речь

Comment: а как вы тогда задачу реализуете? т.е. теперь я не понимаю, может я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Для примера, у меня есть код для этой же задачи только без конструктора: int r=10;
    int x=20;
    int y=20;
if (x*x+y*y<=r*r) {
    cout<<"ne nahoditsya"<< endl;
}
else if  (x*x+y*y>=r*r) {
    cout<<"nahoditsya"<< endl;
}
return 0;
}

Comment: а классы вы знаете? ведь задача, как я понимаю, в том, чтобы создать класс соответствующий и прописать ему методы

Comment: Как вы могли заметить, не очень получается

Comment: добавил в конце своего ответа код, который возможно вам и нужен, во всяком случае с ним можно работать дальше